# Object not found! 404 error

Tags: php, webserver, localhost

Can't access any files (in folders) directly in browser. Why?

I get a 404 error.

For example, if I try to navigate to http://elfgarden.am/asata/ then the image file name ... it display s a 404 error.

I'm just curious if this normal? Or is it a block on my server?

I created a simple PHP file and added it to one of my plugin folders. Then I tried to simply navigate to that PHP file in the browser. But it displays a 404 error.

I'm just curious if this is the way things "should" behave, or if something needs to be changed to allow PHP files (in my plugin folders) to be accessible from the browser (or is this a security issue).

Comment: it means something doesn't exist https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404

Comment: This is my full path http://elfgarden.am/asata/icon.png
I just want to view my icon in web, also i`ve checked many times -- the file exists in that folder - everything is correct

Comment: there is nothing inside `http://elfgarden.am/asata/` - all other .png files are under `http://elfgarden.am/modules/mod_jbgmusic/images/` so your question is impossible to answer. Use error reporting.